# Criar método que pegue a hora digitada

Tags: java, swing

Como eu posso criar um método que pegue a hora digitada em um campo?

Ele vai pegar o conteúdo do campo para salvar no banco de dados. Eu uso pojo e Dao.

Fiz um exemplo bem resumido, o que eu preciso fazer é um metodo que pegue esse conteudo String e possa salvar como Time ou `TimeStamp` no banco.

o que eu tentei fazer foi:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Hora extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hora t = new Hora();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Pojo pojo = new Pojo();

    JFormattedTextField campoHora = new JFormattedTextField();
    JButton pegar = new JButton("Pegar");

    public Hora() {
        setSize(450, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##");
            mf.install(campoHora);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(campoHora);
        campoHora.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));

        painel.add(pegar);
        pegar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 22));
        acao();

        add(painel);
    }

    private void pegaPojo() {
        pojo.setHora(campoHora.getValorTime());
    }

    private void acao() {
        pegar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //campoHora.getValorTime();
            }
        });
    }

    private Time getValorTime() {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            return sdf.parse(getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível obter a hora!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class Pojo {

    private Time hora;

    public Time getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Time hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida. basta um gettext() no campo para você pegar a informação dele. Qual a dificuldade que está tendo?

Comment: @diegofm desculpe, eu não fui claro com o  que eu precisava, editei a pergunta, agora acredito que faça sentido.

Comment: Não pode ser tipo Date?

Comment: Eu faria isso utilizando 3 spinners(um para hora, outro pra minuto e outro pra segundo), pois ai você tem muito mais controle do que é digitado sem precisar ficar fazendo um monte de conversoes e tratamentos.

Comment: @diegofm eu queria salvar só a hora, minutos e segundos. No banco os  atributos  são do tipo TimeStamp, pode dar problema ? estou aberto a sugestões, se você acha melhor, é bem vindo !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz poucas alterações no código e funcionou sem problemas, pegando a hora do campo no clique:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Hora extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Hora t = new Hora();
            t.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    JFormattedTextField campoHora = new JFormattedTextField();
    JButton pegar = new JButton("Pegar");

    public Hora() {
        setSize(450, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##");
            mf.install(campoHora);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(campoHora);
        campoHora.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));

        painel.add(pegar);
        pegar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 22));
        acao();

        add(painel);
    }

    private void acao() {
        pegar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(campoHora.getText()).getTime()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível obter a hora!");
                    campoHora.setText("");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, ele transforma o tipo `Date` para o formato [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), que pode ser salvo num campo semelhante no seu banco.

Mas eu faria utilizando [**JSpinners**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), pois ai você pode controlar melhor o que é informado, sem precisar ficar tratando se a hora é válida ou não. Caso se interesse, aqui tem um [exemplo de uso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478969/5524514) dele somente com horas, minutos e segundos.

Comment: eu usei o exemplo do Spinner, bem melhor mesmo. So uma coisa, ele me da um erro, sera que é a formatação ? o erro é: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:432)

Comment: @Javinha sun,uitl,calendar? Você não está usando a classe errada? A classe certa é java.util.Calendar.

Comment: fiz igual o exemplo acima, unica difereça é que como criei um componente com o spinner ai não preciso colocar o campo diretamente, so assim @Override
    public Object getValor() 
    {
        try 
        {     
            SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            return new java.sql.Timestamp(sdft.parse((String) getValor()).getTime());         
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível obter a Hora!");
            e.printStackTrace();    return null;        }    }

Comment: @Javinha sem ver o que você mudou no seu código ou o que você adicionou, eu não consigo te ajudar.  O exemplo lá é simples, não tive problema ao executá-lo. Alguma mudança que você fez é que deve estar gerando esse erro.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JxszV5i5

Comment: @Javinha porque você ta criando um método pra chamar ele dentro da ação? Fora que você está chamando esse getValor de forma recursiva.

Comment: porque se eu usar em outras telas depois eu uso ele. Mais é isso que causou o erro ?

Comment: @Javinha você não pode chamar o proprio método dentro dele dessa forma. Entrou num loop infinito, por isso o erro. Altere a linha de return para o seguinte: `return new java.sql.Timestamp(((Date)spinner.getModel().getValue()).getTime());`